# Pandas: How to sum data of n days sampled uniformly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below, which is data collected over a period of one year at a frequency of 15 minutes. What I wish to do is add a days data with the next days data.

What I want to do is sum Day 1 data **with** Day 2 data and so on for n days without using loops?

For example:

Day 1 data is:

```
dttm_utc
2012-06-02 00:00:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:05:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:10:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:15:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:20:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 00:25:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:30:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:35:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:40:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:45:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 00:50:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 00:55:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:00:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:05:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:10:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 01:15:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:20:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:25:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:30:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 01:35:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:40:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:45:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 01:50:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 01:55:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 02:00:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 02:05:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 02:10:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 02:15:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 02:20:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 02:25:00    13.9678
                        ...   
2012-06-02 21:30:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 21:35:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 21:40:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 21:45:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 21:50:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 21:55:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 22:00:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 22:05:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 22:10:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 22:15:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 22:20:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 22:25:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 22:30:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 22:35:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 22:40:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 22:45:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 22:50:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 22:55:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:00:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:05:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 23:10:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:15:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:20:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 23:25:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:30:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:35:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:40:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:45:00     6.9839
2012-06-02 23:50:00    13.9678
2012-06-02 23:55:00    13.9678
```

Similary, day 2 data is:

```
2012-06-04 00:00:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 00:05:00      6.9839
2012-06-04 00:10:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 00:15:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 00:20:00      6.9839
2012-06-04 00:25:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 00:30:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 00:35:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 00:40:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 00:45:00      6.9839
2012-06-04 00:50:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 00:55:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:00:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:05:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:10:00      6.9839
2012-06-04 01:15:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:20:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:25:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:30:00      6.9839
2012-06-04 01:35:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:40:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:45:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 01:50:00      6.9839
2012-06-04 01:55:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 02:00:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 02:05:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 02:10:00      6.9839
2012-06-04 02:15:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 02:20:00     13.9678
2012-06-04 02:25:00     13.9678
                         ...   
2012-06-04 21:30:00    160.6302
2012-06-04 21:35:00    146.6623
2012-06-04 21:40:00    146.6623
2012-06-04 21:45:00    146.6623
2012-06-04 21:50:00    146.6623
2012-06-04 21:55:00    153.6462
2012-06-04 22:00:00    146.6623
2012-06-04 22:05:00    146.6623
2012-06-04 22:10:00    146.6623
2012-06-04 22:15:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 22:20:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 22:25:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 22:30:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 22:35:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 22:40:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 22:45:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 22:50:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 22:55:00    132.6945
2012-06-04 23:00:00    139.6784
2012-06-04 23:05:00    111.7427
2012-06-04 23:10:00    118.7266
2012-06-04 23:15:00    111.7427
2012-06-04 23:20:00    118.7266
2012-06-04 23:25:00    132.6945
2012-06-04 23:30:00    132.6945
2012-06-04 23:35:00    132.6945
2012-06-04 23:40:00    125.7106
2012-06-04 23:45:00    125.7106
2012-06-04 23:50:00    132.6945
2012-06-04 23:55:00    132.6945
```

Comment: Do you mean "sum the values for day 1, then add them to the sum of values for day 2"?

Comment: I mean sum day_1[0] with day_2[0], day_1[1] with day_2[1] and so on. Till the end of the days.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need:

```
print (df.groupby(df.index.time)['dttm_utc'].sum())
00:00:00    27.9356
00:05:00    20.9517
00:10:00    27.9356
00:15:00    27.9356
00:20:00    13.9678
00:25:00    27.9356
00:30:00    27.9356
00:35:00    27.9356
00:40:00    27.9356
00:45:00    20.9517
00:50:00    20.9517
00:55:00    27.9356
01:00:00    27.9356
...
...
```

Or:

```
print (df.resample('D').sum())

            dttm_utc
2012-06-02  202.5331
2012-06-03       NaN
2012-06-04  230.4687
```

Comment: Sorry jezrael, I would like to sum the values of each series. I mean sum day_1[0] with day_2[0], day_1[1] with day_2[1] and so on. Till the end of the days. I will fix my question.

Comment: jesrael: My entire data is in a single df. An year's worth of data. I don't have a df2. I have to extract each day's data from df and add them to the next day's data. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. Can you get shorted data samples, (3-4 rows) with desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use `sum(zip(day_1['value_column'], day_2['value_column']))`?